Oregon recording laws
In Oregon, is it legal for a participant to make a surreptitious recording of a videoconference call (Zoom or similar) without first obtaining consent from ALL the other participants?

Zoom, in particular, gives a standard notice in every meeting that it is being recorded. Other providers may vary.

And if a cell phone or other video recording device is used to record the call/screen? My concern is a) do I need consent, if yes b) do i need consent from all parties on the videoconference call or would i alone as a participant to the videoconference call be sufficient?

I don't have time to write an answer, but it is summarized at https://www.shannonpowelllaw.com/blog/the-oregon-recording-laws-guide

@ohwilleke I'm not sure that answers the question, though. In the context of phone calls to call centers, I've often wondered whether a customer-service agent's knowledge of and consent to their employer's recording necessarily constitutes consent to the customer's recording, as well. I think it should, but I've never seen an answer.

Oregon is a two-party consent state. So all parties have to consent to the recording.

But if you're notified that the call is being recorded, you give your consent by staying on the call. They don't have to ask each participant beforehand.
